# Ошибка при сборке: "Module parse failed: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

Файл **index.js**

```
import App from './app';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Файл **app.js**

```
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Файл **webpack.config**

```
const path = require('path');
const conf = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: 'dist/'
  }
};

module.exports = conf;
```

Ошибка при сборке:

> ```
> ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:2
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:2)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> |
> | ReactDOM.render((
> >   <BrowserRouter>
> |     <App />
> |   </BrowserRouter>
>  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js main[1]
> ```

Не понимаю, как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Прочитать документацию по сборке реактового приложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всей видимости не могут распознаться открывающиеся и закрывающиеся скобки тэгов `<` и `>`. Эта ошибка достаточно часто возникает при начале работы с React. Решение является простым, вам поможет *"бабелизация"*.

Первое, что нужно сделать - это добавить файл `.babelrc` в тот же каталог, где лежит файл `package.json`. В этом файле необходимо указать пресет `react` и `env`, получится вот такой файл:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Не так давно бабел переехал в монорепу, поэтому в обновленном формате это выглядит так:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Данный файл `.babelrc` - сообщит babel, какие из пресетов использовать для транспайлинга кода. Обращу ваше внимание, что последовательность указания пресетов важна.

Перед тем, как добавлять файл конфигурации бабела, нужно установить парочку пакетов, для всего этого добра:

- [`babel-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader) - транспайлинг кода и задание пресетов
- [`babel-core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core) - преобразует код ES6 в ES5
- [`babel-preset-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react) - пресет, преобразующий JSX в JavaScript
- [`babel-preset-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-env) - пресет конвертации кода ES6, ES7 и ES8 в код ES5

По ссылкам можно найти и примеры и документацию. Самая важная для вас ссылка - это [`babel-preset-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react). Ну и `webpack.config` конечно же нужно дописать:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },
      }
    ]
  }
```

Здесь `babel-loader` используется для загрузки наших JSX/JavaScript файлов.

Также, я рекомендую вам посмотреть в сторону `style-loader` и `css-loader`. Так `css-loader` для загрузки и объединения всех CSS файлов в один, а `style-loader` добавит все стили внутрь тега документа style. А еще, раз уж на то пошло, то и `html-webpack-plugin` не помешает - плагин генерирует HTML файл, затем вставляет в него скрипт и записывает файл в `dist/index.html`.